# Is there a block syntax for sbt ThisBuild scope?

Tags: scala, sbt

Given a multimodule `build.sbt`:

```
ThisBuild / organization := "com.mycompany"
ThisBuild / version := "1.0.0"
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.7"
// more global settings
```

The `ThisBuild` scope is repeated on every single line. Is there a way to do the following?

```
ThisBuild {
  organization := "com.mycompany"
  version := "1.0.0"
  scalaVersion := "2.12.7"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the closest you can get is:

```
inThisBuild(Seq(
  organization := "com.mycompany",
  version := "1.0.0",
  scalaVersion := "2.12.7"
))
```